# Q deep learning algorithm not working

Tags: c#, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

been trying to implement a Q deep learning algorithm, having an issue though, its not working, after 100 000 game plays and using 1000 iterations to train each step (although i have tried lower numbers for both) it's still not learning. Network and game are in the linked image, https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaC35.jpg here is what happens in each training step:

```
double maxQval;
double[] inputvec;
int MaxQ = GetRandDir(state, out maxQval, out inputvec);//input vec is board
double[] QtarVec = new double[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
double r = GetR((int)state[0], (int)state[1]); // GetR is reward
QtarVec[MaxQ] = Qtar(r, maxQval); // backprop vector of 0's except Qtar replaces a value

associator.Train(50, new double[][] { inputvec }, new double[][] { QtarVec });​
```

Training data pair for backprop is (input i linked in image,QTarget = r + gamma * MaxQ) , MaxQ is max network output layer activation or a random one (epsilon greedy). r is reward obtained from each move, -10 for obstacle and 10 for goal. (althogh I have tried just 10 for goal and 0 for everything else. Here is training code.

```
public void Train(int nTrails)
{
    double[] state = new double[] { 1, 1 }; // inital position
    int its = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nTrails; i++)
    {
        while (((state[0] < 4) && (state[1] < 4))&&((state[0] * 100 >0) && (state[1] * 100 >0)) && (state[0] != 3 && state[1] != 3))//while on board and not at goal     postion
        {
            double temp = r.NextDouble();
            int next = -1;
            lines.Add(new Vector2((float)(state[0] * 100), (float)(state[1] * 100)));
            if (temp < epsilon)
            {
                next = TrainRandIt(state); // move random direction, backprop
            }
            else
            {
                next = TrainMaxIt(state); // move in max activation direction, backprop
            }
            if (next == 0) .//updating postion
            {
                state[0]++;
            }
            else if (next == 1)
            {
                state[0]--;
            }
            else if (next == 2)
            {
                state[1]++;
            }
            else if (next == 3)
            {
                state[1]--;
            }
        }
    }
    state[0] = 1;
    state[1] = 1; // resetting game

}
```

Any Help appreciated.

Comment: Indentation make it easy to read the code.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the linked image you provided, it is just like a maze game where you have inputs for the player's position and the output as the direction the player should move to (up, down, left or right).

Here is a machine learning engine which is able to solve exactly that and more - the [Ryskamp Learning Machine](http://useaible.com/code/) (RLM). The RLM has a different approach compared to the typical machine learning engines that you may have tried so far so I suggest you go to the link I've provided to learn more about it and what makes it different.

It is written in C# and we have an example of the Maze game just like the one you are trying out which you can browse through our [Github page](https://github.com/useaible/RyskampLearningMachine) or even try it yourself by cloning/downloading the source code together with the examples apps provided.

For documentation, you may refer to the [Documentations files](https://github.com/useaible/RyskampLearningMachine/tree/master/Documentation) provided or even through the [github wiki](https://github.com/useaible/RyskampLearningMachine/wiki).

The RLM is also available via [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/useAIble.RyskampLearningMachine/).